# Why Is Scope Resolution Operator Needed In CPP File

Tags: c++, scope, include

Why is LinkedList::List* LinkedList::getMiddleNode() necessary after we already included LinkedList.h? As I understand include, it should import all file variables (which is struct List), and declarations.

Here's the header file.

```
class LinkedList{

private:
    struct List {
        int num;

        List* next;
    };
    List* head;

public:
    ...
    ...
    List* getMiddleNode();
};
```

Now here's the CPP File.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::List* LinkedList::getMiddleNode() {
    ...
    ...
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Note that unlike some other languages, there is no connection between files and classes. A function can be defined in any source file.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is LinkedList::List* LinkedList::getMiddleNode() necessary after we already included LinkedList.h?

Because compiler needs to know that you are defining method of class `LinkedList` and not a standalone function. Nobody would stop you to declare/define standalone function as well as method like this:

```
class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList::List* LinkedList::getMiddleNode();
    ...
};

LinkedList::List* getMiddleNode();
```

How would you tell compiler which one is which?

Comment: And not a member function with the same name in a different class.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is `LinkedList::List* LinkedList::getMiddleNode()` necessary after
>   we already included *LinkedList.h*? As I understand include, it should
>   import all file variables (which is struct List), and declarations.

Apart from the possibility of defining non-member functions separate from its declaration elsewhere; what if you have multiple visible class with the same function name? How do you separately define its member functions out of class? So, that's C++'s way to define a member function outside a class definition. To quote (emphasis mine):

> **[[class.mem/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#class.mfct-4):** If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class
>   definition, **the member function name shall be qualified by its class
>   name using the ​::​ operator.** *[ Note:* A name used in a member function
>   definition (that is, in the parameter-declaration-clause including the
>   default arguments ([dcl.fct.default]) or in the member function body)
>   is looked up as described in [basic.lookup].  *— end note ] [ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct X {
>   typedef int T;
>   static T count;
>   void f(T);
> };
> void X::f(T t = count) { }
> ```
>
> The member function `f` of `class X` is defined in global scope; the
>   notation `X​::​f` specifies that the function `f` is a member of `class X`
>   and in the scope of `class X`. In the function definition, the parameter
>   type `T` refers to the typedef member `T` declared in `class X` and the
>   default argument count refers to the static data member count declared
>   in `class X`. * — end example ]*